Hodge decomposition on a riemannian manifold for another measure?
Let $M$ be a closed riemannian manifold, we denote $dx$ the canonic volume measure on $M$. If we take $\mu$ a probability measure such that $d\mu = \rho dx$ with $\rho > 0$ we can define $d_\mu^*$ such that for $\alpha$ a $k$-form and $\beta$ a $(k+1)$-form we get
\begin{equation}
\int_M \langle d\alpha, \beta \rangle d\mu = \int_M \langle \alpha, d_\mu^* \beta \rangle d\mu
\end{equation}
because we have
\begin{equation}
\int_M \langle d\alpha, \beta \rangle d\mu = \int_M \langle d\alpha, \rho \beta \rangle dx = \int_M \langle \alpha, d^*(\rho \beta) \rangle dx = \int_M \langle \alpha, \rho^{-1} d^*(\rho \beta) \rangle d\mu
\end{equation}
In particular, we get that $d_\mu^* \circ d_\mu^* = 0$ and we can define the following operator $\Box_\mu := d \circ d_\mu^* + d_\mu^* \circ d $. We can also give a sense to the forms "$\mu$-harmonics" i.e forms such that $\Box_\mu \omega = 0$.
My question is the following : do we have a "hodge decomposition" for these operators, i.e can we write any $k$-form $\omega$
\begin{equation}
\omega = d \omega_1 + d_\mu^* \omega_2 + h
\end{equation}
with $h$ a $\mu$-harmonic form ? If yes, do you have any references ?
Thank you.

This may be naive but I think it works: simply define a new inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_\mu = \rho \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle $ and you have another Riemannian manifold structure.  Apply Hodge to this Riemannian manifold.

I have a doubt because in the Hodges decomposition we consider the volume form canonically associated to our riemannian metric and à priori this one is different of my original volume measure no ?
